# Unable to use internet in Laptop by "USB tether mode" from smart phone?

Tags: windows-8, usb, internet-connection

I have recently installed Windows 8 Pro in my laptop, and now I find that I am not able to use internet in my laptop by "USB Tethering" from my Android 2.3 Gingerbread based Samsung Galaxy Y mobile phone.

What should I do? How do I fix it?

Comment: How are you going about it? What happens when you try? Any specific errors?

Comment: You should check the drivers and check that Kies is installed correctly.

Comment: @Karan No errors, nothing. Just not able to use internet in laptop at all.